# Get temp folder using WSH script

Tags: javascript, wsh

How to get temp folder path using WSH script ?

Comment: What about asking google? One of the first results http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee156595.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Save this script as tempFolder.js and double click to execute.

```
var WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell");
var temp = WshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%TEMP%");
WScript.Echo(temp);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set WshEnv = WshShell.Environment

strVar1="TEMP"
strVar2="TMP"

WScript.Echo ".... System   ............................. Environment " & strVar1 & "," & strVar2
WScript.Echo WshShell.Environment("System").Item(strVar1)
WScript.Echo WshShell.Environment("System").Item(strVar2)

WScript.Echo ".... User     ............................. Environment " & strVar1 & "," & strVar2
WScript.Echo WshShell.Environment("User").Item(strVar1)
WScript.Echo WshShell.Environment("User").Item(strVar2)

WScript.Echo ".... Volatile ............................. Environment " & strVar1 & "," & strVar2
WScript.Echo WshShell.Environment("Volatile").Item(strVar1)
WScript.Echo WshShell.Environment("Volatile").Item(strVar2)

WScript.Echo ".... Process  ............................. Environment " & strVar1 & "," & strVar2
WScript.Echo WshShell.Environment("Process").Item(strVar1)
WScript.Echo WshShell.Environment("Process").Item(strVar2)

WScript.Echo "....          ............................. Environment " & strVar1 & "," & strVar2
WScript.Echo WshShell.Environment.Item(strVar1)
WScript.Echo WshShell.Environment.Item(strVar2)

WScript.Echo "....          ................ ExpandEnvironmentStrings " & strVar1 & "," & strVar2
WScript.Echo WshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%"& strVar1 &"%")
WScript.Echo WshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%"& strVar2 &"%")
```